# Connect to an internal port without external access

Tags: php, html, apache, security

I require external access to a local server (localhost:xxxx) through my apache server on port 80.

Is there any way to achieve this in php or other scripting languages so that I don't have to port forward the other server?

Basically is there any way to have a script that loads the other server then pushes it through the apache server.

notes: I don't have the ability to modify the other server, it will be only the apache server that I can modify files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have

1. one server running on port XXXX (not 80) which is not accessible publicly
2. an Apache server running on port 80 which is accessible publicly

and you want a way to make 1. accessible through 2.

If your Apache server has mod_rewrite and/or mod_proxy installed, this can be as easy as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^somepath/ http://localhost:XXXX [P]
```

This will use Apache as reverse-proxy to the other server. Can be put into the Apache configuration or an .htaccess file. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html.

Comment: Brilliant that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I ended up using: 
    `ProxyRequests Off`

    `ProxyPreserveHost On` 

    `ProxyPass /somepath/ localhost:XXXX/webroot/`

    `ProxyPassReverse /somepath/ localhost:XXXX/webroot/`

Its case sensitive and i had to use backslashes in those locations for it to work.